# SharePoint Discussion List TreeView Visual webpart

Tags: jquery, list, sharepoint, treeview

trying to create a visual webpart to render SharePoint 2010 discussion board as a treeview. 
I can get back all the topics as the parent nodes and all the replies for each topics as child nodes but not with the hierarchy. So all replies (even the reply to earlier replies) are on the same node level. There is a property called ThreadIndex that can be used to track what level is the reply at on the hierarchy(whether it is the first reply or reply to the first reply or {reply to the first reply's reply} etc. The long number between the two line is the threadingindex value. you can see how first reply has certain threading index value and reply to it has its threading index value with some random string appended to it..

This is what it looks like:
[what mine looks like http://www.resizr.com/resized/d2eb.jpg](http://www.resizr.com/resized/d2eb.jpg)

This is what I want it to look like:
[Desired http://www.resizr.com/resized/8249.jpg](http://www.resizr.com/resized/8249.jpg)

Can some one give me some hint?

```
public partial class HDRDiscussionTreeUserControl : UserControl
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> allTopics = new List<string>();
        List<string> allreplies = new List<string>();
        List<int> allpids = new List<int>();
        HDRDiscussionTV.Nodes.Clear();          
        TreeNode node;
        SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWeb web = currentSite.RootWeb;
        //Get the Discussion list
        SPList lst = web.Lists["SP2017Discussion"];

        SPQuery query0 = new SPQuery();
        //get all topics
        query0.Query = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /></IsNotNull></Where>";
        SPListItemCollection col = lst.GetItems(query0);

        foreach (SPListItem item in col)
        { 
            //listItem.Fields["Parent Folder Id"].GetFieldValueAsText(listItem["Parent Folder Id"]).ToString() 
            //string pfid = item.Fields["Parent Folder Id"].GetFieldValueAsText(item["Parent Folder Id"]).ToString();
            int id = item.ID;
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            SPListItem topic = item;
            //allTopics.Add(item.Title);

            node = new TreeNode(item.Title);
            HDRDiscussionTV.Nodes.Add(node);

             SPQuery query1 = new SPQuery();
            query1.Folder = item.Folder;
             //get all replies
            SPListItemCollection relatedDiscussions = lst.GetItems(query1);
            try
            {
                if (relatedDiscussions.Count != 0)
                {
                    int n = 1;
                    TreeNode parentNode1 = node;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= relatedDiscussions.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //int parentListID = Convert.ToInt32(relatedDiscussions[i].Fields["Parent Folder Id"].GetFieldValueAsText(relatedDiscussions[i]["Parent Folder Id"]));
                        string threading = relatedDiscussions[i]["ThreadIndex"].ToString();
                        string checkthreading = relatedDiscussions[n]["ThreadIndex"].ToString();
                        node = new TreeNode(relatedDiscussions[i]["ows_TrimmedBody"].ToString()+"|" + threading + "|");
                        parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(node);
                         n = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use treeview control?
http://hamidseta.blogspot.com/2012/01/check-uncheck-all-checkbox-in-treeview.html